# What is static_case operator in C++?

Tags: c++

I've heard of [**static_cast operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9(VS.80).aspx)

Recently I've come across **static_case**, for instance:

```
*ppv = static_case<IUnknown>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: sb plz correct a type in question topic and source code

Comment: @Nazgob: huh? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @Atklin: Somebody please correct the typo in the question topic and source code

Comment: In the question, I'm indicating what is a static_case - not what is the static_cast operator

Comment: Atklin. yeah i don't agree with the downvote. i will upvote it so it's zero again. but now with your title "(misprint)" behind it, it sounds quit strange. i mean, the answer there is already in the question. better you leave it as it was i think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a typo : **there is no static_case**, [only static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting.html).

You can see [on google](http://www.google.fr/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_frFR299FR303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%2B%2B+static_case) that the docs where you find "static_case" have typos and use static_cast and static_case like if it was the same word.

To be sure, just try to use static_case in available compilers.

Comment: Nice - thanks Klaim - I'll keep the question up in case others get confused... I'm new to C++

Comment: No problem. May I suggest you try using example of keyword usage in you compiler before asking? That would help you check first it that keyword is a language keyword or a library function (like boost ones) or simply a typo.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing called **static_case** in C++. There is just **static_cast**

Answer (score 0):

Its good old C cast with a new C++ syntax similar to other C++ cast like dynamic_cast. The only advantage I know is just being consistent and also it's easy to grep it.

CPP Ref: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/static_cast

Stroustrup on static_cast: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#static-cast

Comment: Any info on static_case, specifically?

Comment: Updated my response, check out the links but not really. It's just casting a type from one to other without any fancy features.

Comment: You're missing the point. He's asking about *static_case* not static_cast.

Comment: There is no static_case AFAIK... I assumed it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Static operator for casting object.It's concept for upcast object and downcast object.If you read inheritance object topic,it's can help you.
Casting in c++ : http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds3-1/ovp3-1.html

Answer (score 0):

the first thing I thought of when I looked at this question - it`s a simple misprint